# Elasticsearch sort by nested object

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

i'm just discovering elasticsearch and i'm trying to make my first queries. for example in my case, each article has several prices, I would like to sort these articles by minimum price. and therefore I would not take the other ones into consideration. it is only the minimum prices that will have to sort my articles.
here are my articles :

```
{
           "name": "john",
           "prices": [
              {
                 "price": "22"
              },
              {
                 "price": "28"
              },
              {
                 "price": "8"
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "peter",
           "prices": [
              {
                 "price": "7"
              },
              {
                 "price": "5"
              },
              {
                 "price": "2"
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "billy",
           "prices": [
              {
                 "price": "15"
              },
              {
                 "price": "17"
              }
           ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
POST /_search

{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort" : [
        {
            "prices.price": {
                "order": "asc",
                "mode" : "min"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: If your `prices` objects are of `nested` type (and not `object`) then you also need to add the `"nested_path": "prices"` inside the `prices.price`.

More info on sorting can be found here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

Comment: may be we need to use GET method instead of POST , If yes so please update your answer

Comment: @Manishsharma ElasticSearch supports both GET and POST HTTP methods in [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html). And because in our example we are also sending data inside the body of the request, it should be POST, and not GET. Because GET, should not be used to send data in request body - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET